# scriptcs: how to load a web reference

Tags: scriptcs

I have a microsoft reporting server that i'd like to create some scriptcs against.

I know how to do this from within a VS project, by adding a web reference to some resource such as: https://rsdev1.myDomain/RSDEV1/ReportService2005.asmx

How does one accomplish this from a .csx?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating a vs project of type class library, then after copying this dll to my scriptcs bin folder it all works.